# Python average color over square region

Tags: python, image

I'm using four inputs for my function: a picture object, x coordinate, y coordinate, and the height/width of the square. I want to separately average all the red, green, and blue values of the picture. I'm having trouble with the accumulator variables of the RGB pixels and checking the bounds of the square. Can anyone help me out?

```
from imageTools import *

p1 = makePicture("flower.jpg")

def averageColor(pic, xCord, yCord, width):
    rAcc = 0 
    gAcc = 0
    bAcc = 0 
    for x in range(xCord, xCord + width):
        for y in range(yCord, yCord + width):
            picWidth = getWidth(pic)
            picHeight = getHeight(pic)
            if x <= picWidth and y <= picHeight:
                pixel = getPixel(pic, xCord, yCord)
                r = getRed(pixel)
                g = getGreen(pixel)
                b = getBlue(pixel)
                rAcc = rAcc + 1
                gAcc = gAcc + 1
                bAcc = bAcc + 1
    avgRed = r / rAcc
    avgGreen = g / gAcc
    avgBlue = b / bAcc
    newColor = makeColor(avgRed, avgGreen, avgBlue)
    return newColor

col1 = averageColor(p1, 0, 150, 100)
print(col1)
```

Comment: aren't you supposed to *sum* the `r`, `g` and `b` values, `r += getRed(pixel)` and so on...

Comment: Do you get any kind of error? You are assigning the pixel value to `r`, `g` and `b` for every pixel, and then only doing one calculation with it at the end?

Comment: I don't want the average of the r g and b values, I want to form a new color using the average color over the region

Comment: Yes, I'm getting "local variable rAcc referenced before assignment"

Comment: I think a lot of these problems could be diagnosed using the debugger, for instance you would quickly see that xCord and yCord are being used to get the pixel, so for every iteration of the for loops you are getting the **same** pixel.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use < and not <= when comparing indexes because indexes are zero based.  For instance if the picture is 10 pixels wide 9 is the index to the last pixel

Also you are overwriting your accumulation variables r, g and b. You need to do

```
r = r + getRed(...)
```

oh. Also it looks like you are trying to use xCoord and yCoord to get the pixel rather than your x and y variables

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am just wondering why I am still getting an accumulator variable referenced before assignment error.

Comment: If you never get in That loop you will never assign your accumulator variables

Comment: @SCarey was this enough to help you figure it out on your own?